# Is there any possibility that there is an error by modified closure in the following code?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, closures

It is my understanding that the following code is safe as the Invoke is synchronous so the index is always increased after the action but I'm getting a report of an ArgumentOutOfRangeException at the `array.ElementAt(index)` line.

array is an IEnumerable generated from a LINQ query just before this code so it cannot be modified.

```
IEnumerable array = collection.Select(() => .....);

while (index < array.Count())
{
    this.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        ...
        object a = array.ElementAt(index)
        ...
    }), DispatcherPriority.Input);

    index++;
}
```

The only way I can imagine to get the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is if, somehow, index gets increased before the array is accessed.

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: What is `collection`? Do you realize that you're evaluating the `Select` part on each call of `Count` and on each call of `ElementAt`? The name "array" here is very misleading...

Comment: What's inside your `Enumerable.Select` method? The underlying query may yield different results every time you invoke `ElementAt` and `Count` as you're not materializing the query

Comment: Ok I get your point. How can I materialize the query? Can you put it as an answer?

Comment: Add `.ToList()` after your `Select`. Then your Enumerated will be "matrialized" and you can talk about array/List. `collection.Select(() => .....).ToList();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `array` is lazy evaluated change in the collection could cause index to be out of range (i.e. removing elements from `collection`) even if you've corrected code with cached local variable.

Or as pointed in comments condition in `Select` may return different results every time it is executed.

Note that if you have R# you would be getting "possible multiple enumerations" warning as `array.Count()` and `array.ElementAt()` both need to iterate over collection to achieve results. So you really re-executing `Select` multiple times over `while` loop.

Fix:

- perform single iteration with `foreach` (preferable)
- force evaluation of enumerable with `ToList()` call before performing iteration (which will also bring down O(n^2) complexity of loop to `O(n)` as `Count` and `ElementAt` will be O(1) instead of at least O(n) when used on `IEnumerable<T>`).

Answer (score 3):

As you understand from comments your query will be executed every time you call `array.Count` or `array.ElementAt(index)`.
Every execution can return different result it can be reason for your Exception.
Use `.ToList()` extension method which "materialize" result of query to `List<T>`, which can be safely used

```
List array = collection.Select(() => .....).ToList();
```

Since your code simply looping result of query, consider using @Alexei's suggestion to loop enumeration only once

```
IEnumerable array = collection.Select(() => .....);

foreach(var item in array)
{
    this.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        //...
        object a = item;
        //...
    }), DispatcherPriority.Input);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is called a closure.. just define local variable instead of using index.

One more suggestion is to use ToList in the end of linq query so that Select is not evaluated at every call of Count and ElementAt

```
var array = collection.Select(() => .....).ToList();

while (index < array.Count())
{
      int index_dup = index
    this.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        ...
        object a = array.ElementAt(index_dup)
        ...
    }), DispatcherPriority.Input);

    index++;
}
```

Comment: Closure is not related to the problem as OP explicitly said "code is safe as the Invoke is synchronous...". `ToList` is likely the solution.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, you are correct Invoke is synchronous so control will return only after delegate is executed.Incase of BeginInvoke, Closure would have been problem. .